# Trying to set up Grunt to automate some testing, testing works fine in the browser but not at the command line

Tags: phantomjs, gruntjs, qunit

I'm currently trying to incorporate GruntJS with a few plugins (PhantomJS Qunit and Connect plugins). However, setting up a simple test is throwing me errors and I can't find the solution despite a few days of searching. I'm using a local web server (MAMP) and the website is running on a CMS.

Running the tests by accessing the test template in a browser works fine, but when trying to access the same tools via the command line using `sudo grunt test` PhantomJS return an odd error:

```
Running "qunit:all" (qunit) task
Testing http://user-guides:80/test/test.html 
Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing QUnit start() call. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Some of my searches had people downgrading their version of phantom.js to deal with similar problems, but so far none of those solutions have worked for me, and I'm afraid i'm missing something right in front of my face.

Here's the contents of my Gruntfile.js

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),   
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    hostname: 'user-guides',
                    port: 80,
                    base: 'public'
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'public/assets/js/helper/*.js', 'public/assets/js/specific/*.js']
        },
        qunit: {
        all: {
          options: {
            timeout: 5000,
            urls: [
              'http://user-guides:80/test/test.html',
            ]
          }
        }
    }
    }
    );

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['connect', 'qunit']);
};
```

Here's the simple Qunit test

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/lib/qunit.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <script src="/assets/lib/qunit.js"></script>

  <script>
console.log("====TEST===");
    start();
    test( "hello test", function() {
      ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you certain PhantomJS runs by itself without errors? Test that PhantomJS runs without errors by executing the bin file in here from the cmd line: `node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/bin`

Comment: I am using OSX. I realized that I didn't have PhantomJS in my PATH, and I added it to use PhantomJS directly from the command line and a test using `phantomjs loadspeed.js http://www.google.com` works correctly. I'm really baffled by this.

Comment: @TrevorP, did you end up figuring this out? I believe I have the same issue...

Answer (score 6):

In my test.html file I originally had just copied the example from the [QUnit Cookbook](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#introduction)

After finding a similar (possibly the same) issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053808/1814739

I updated:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.js"></script>
```

Running from command-line seems to work after adding http: to the src attribute.

Comment: Solved the Problem, Thx

Comment: I searched for hours to solve that problem. Thank you. The error is very misleading

Comment: Thank you Lord Devil for teaching me after thousand hours that I had to prefix the URL with HTTP://