# QunitJS-Tests don't start: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing QUnit start() call

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, automated-tests, phantomjs, qunit

I have set up my test environment as described here with QunitJS + PhantomJS + GruntJS: http://jordankasper.com/blog/2013/04/automated-javascript-tests-using-grunt-phantomjs-and-qunit/

If I execute the tests (grunt task) locally everything works fine. But If I try to execute the tests on our buildserver it throws following error:

[image]

I checked the URL and path several times and the html-document for starting the qunit tests is also available on the configured path on our build server. Any ideas why this error can occur?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to set up Grunt to automate some testing, testing works fine in the browser but not at the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841023/trying-to-set-up-grunt-to-automate-some-testing-testing-works-fine-in-the-brows)

Comment: I provided an answer to a similar question, which should work for you as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34928952

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The URL configuration for the qunit html file in the Grunt task was not correct!

Comment: can you post the config that solved the issue? your answer is not very helpful otherwise

Comment: *Comment from [David Skx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1138860/david-skx):* izocan, could you please specify your solution? I got the same problem with travis ci. I also tried using connect, but the problem is still there. See: [QUnit on Travis CI (PhantomJS timeout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552132/qunit-on-travis-ci-phantomjs-timeout)

Comment: Maybe you can even look at the question from David and answer it.