# QUnit on Travis CI (PhantomJS timeout)

Tags: gruntjs, continuous-integration, phantomjs

Whenever I try to QUnit-Test on Travis the build fails with a PhantomJS Timeout Error.
See: https://travis-ci.org/misantronic/frameWreck/builds/38939015 from line 86.

On my local system everything just works fine.

Its actually loading all the sources (QUnits.js and my js-module) but as soon as the test() function is invoked, it fails.

I found some topics about this issue, but these were because of the grunt version number (<0.4). Thats not the case.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: nope. but by now there is no need for using phantomJS anymore since we have chrome headless.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  Unfortunately I have some legacy code that depends on PhantomJS :-(